# Setting Up a Test Environment For an ASP.NET MVC3 Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7, configuration

I've been working for a client's website over the past year. I usually test things locally and then deploy straight to the production website. This has caused us some issues lately so I thought I should create a test/staging environment in which we could thoroughly test new features before pushing them into production.

Anyway, we have a VPS hosting account. I usually use remote desktop to manage the website in IIS. So in order to create a test environment, I copy pasted the folder of the production website inside the same directory (so they are both at the same level) and changed the name of the folder. Then I created a new website in IIS and mapped the physical path to the httpdocs folder inside the copied folder. After that, I setup a new application pool which basically has the same settings of the production website's application pool. I also changed the connection string of the test website.

But then when I tried to view the test website, it did not work the way I expected it to do. I keep getting `&ReturnUrl=%2f` appended to the query string, and the website is stripped out of its styles (the CSS). I remember this used to happen before when we were still using a shared hosting account, but I have no idea how to fix that.

I really do not know what's wrong. I basically have the same exact setup except I'm using a different port and a different database. I even tried running the test website with the application pool of the production website, but that did not work either...

Any suggestions?

Comment: looks like permission problem to me, check if your user  has correct privileges in the new folder/app pool

Comment: @torm: Apparently you were right! Could you please add your comment as an answer so I could accept it? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: sure thank you, please give some details what you've changed to make it work for other ppl looking in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like permission problem to me, check if your user has correct privileges in the new folder/app pool :)

Comment: Yup, I actually need to add the IUSR to the folder and give it some permissions. That did the trick, thank you :)